# How to Make another Activity as Main Activity(start up)

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, authentication, manifest

I am trying to create app based on sqlite and i made the app first without login screen but in wrote activity for login but i tried to make that login screen activity as main activity (Start up) error occurs force closed.
i have embedded the manifest file with this post help me to make login activity as start up activity.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.i2i.p1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".P001MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DatabaseHandler"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_database_handler" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Contact"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Add_Update_User"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add__update__user" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignUp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_sign_up" >
    </activity>
  </application>

 </manifest>
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace from logcat.  Unless you show us the error, how will we know?

Comment: I'm no expert, but can you start an activity name with a period (`.`) ?

Comment: @erad, yes, you can. ".Login" would be shorthand for "com.i2i.p1.Login"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make **Login** activity your main activity then put the the **intent-filter** tag inside Login activity. Any activity your want to make your main activity must contain intent-filter tag with action as **main** and category as **launcher**.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```